# universal programming language for android, iphone and windows phone

Tags: android, iphone, ios, windows-phone-7, code-reuse

Hey I am going to write an algorithm for my android application.

Now the issue is Its a big algorithm and I might develop applications for iphone and windows phone also. So i wanted to reuse the code every where.

My question is that which language should i write the algo in to reuse the code.

I have done some research it seems android and iphone support C++ but i am confused with windows phone

> Does windows phone support C++ language

Comment: Have you tried looking at phone gap ? http://phonegap.com/.

Comment: @iNoob:Yes I know about phone gap but it is web based application. It makes html based application and it might not provide me much deeper functionality of the phone which I need so can't use that.

Comment: Oh ok then, by the way I had read that windows 8 will support C++. Here are the links : http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/106087.aspx, http://www.liveside.net/2012/01/28/windows-phone-tango-will-support-120-languages-c-development-support-coming-soon/

Comment: "An algorithm"? Without knowing anything about what you're actually doing, tough to help. Why not run it on a server and give results to phones via a web app? What's a "big" algorithm? Big how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like C++ will come with WP Apollo.

I would do in C++ and wait to see if there are C++ for WP soon enough.

Otherwise, rewrite that code into C#, pretty quick I think.

Comment: hey seems I will do the same. I will write the code in C++. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there has been any confirmation that WP8 will support C++ - can you find a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

- Windows Phone 7 doesn't support C++
- Windows Phone 8 will support C++

Maybe you should take a look at [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch/). It allows you to code in C# and target Windows Phone, iOS and Android.

Comment: I don't think there has been any confirmation that WP8 will support C++ - can you find a reference for this?

Comment: "Windows Phone 8 has full C and C++ support" (source: [official Windows Phone blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/06/20/announcing-windows-phone-8.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows Phone does not support C++ - there is a chance that WP8 will support it, but i din't think that has been made official yet. You have a few options, none of them are ideal!

**MonoTouch / MonoDroid**

You can use Mono to write your application in C# for iOS and Android, and using the regular C# frameworks for Windows Phone. This does mean you will have to use Mono for your entire application, not just this algorithm.

**JavaScript**

You could write your algorithm in JavaScript then run it within a suitable browser control within each platform. Ugly, but viable!

Comment: "Windows Phone 8 has full C and C++ support" (source: [official Windows Phone blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/06/20/announcing-windows-phone-8.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

**WP8 doesn't have full C++ support**.

You can't develop and publish to WP8 app store non-direct3D apps just by using it. You HAVE TO/MUST use C# to design your interface, which is XAML and only compatible with C#. This "You can develop apps with C++ for WP8" slogan is just a big marketing lie. And the indication of WP8's failure. Read my answer here for further and the resources:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/177048/3375